# Can I create multiple elements of the same type using Strapi and GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, strapi

Can I create multiple elements of the same type using Strapi and GraphQL?
For example -

```
createMultipleFoo mutation(data: [
    nameOfFoo: "ooaoaoa",
    weightOfFoo: "aododo"
    ], ....)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the [roadmap](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/42-support-bulk-entries-creation-updates).

What you can do for now is create a custom endpoint ie. "createMulti". Send a json array, and use the "regular" create for each. Check out the [discussion here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1191).

---

**Update Q4 2021**:
Status moved to "In Progress (Development)"

---

**Update Q2 2022**:
The roadmap site has moved, link to the issue:
https://feedback.strapi.io/developer-experience/p/support-bulk-entries-creationupdates-v4

Status marked as "PLANNED"

---