# How to create with array at once in strapi (mongo)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, strapi

I'd like to create datas with array but can't find how should i do.
maybe i put wrong keywords for this question for searching

I have to create a lot of datas at once but It take too long.
when i create about 600 columns of array, it took 30 sec ~ 1 minute to create.

because I'm a beginner for database.
I put `strapi` in for sentence and it's going to check if it's exist in database with `strapi.services[tableName].find()` and then it will be created unless it's exist.

this working is doing as much as how array's length have

I know it's unnecessary. if you know how make that better performance, please let me know

back to the main subject, I tried `strapi.services[tableName].create(array)`.
I expected it's going to create all of datas in the array but it doesn't work like that.

can you let me know how it's going to be better or how to create datas in array at once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create multiple elements of the same type using Strapi and GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260467/can-i-create-multiple-elements-of-the-same-type-using-strapi-and-graphql)

Answer (score 1):

use json instead. its simple..

thats what i know

[image: json content type strapi]

Comment: how we can use unique component attribute in json